# Base Class extended Incorrectly

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, deno

Hey I am using Deno and extending `EventTarget` class but I don't want the end user to be able to get functions which exist on `EventTarget` class like `addEventListener`,`dispatchEvent` and `removeEventListener`. I am doing this right now:

```
class Test extends EventTarget{
    constructor(){
        super()
    }
    private addEventListener(){}
    private dispatchEvent(){}
    private removeEventListener(){}
}
```

But I am getting Error:

```
Class 'Test' incorrectly extends base class 'EventTarget'.
  Property 'addEventListener' is private in type 'Test' but not in type 'EventTarget'
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...but I don't want the end user to be able to get functions which exist on EventTarget class like `addEventListener`,`dispatchEvent` and `removeEventListener`...

Then it's not a subclass of `EventTarget`. A subclass has all the members of its superclass and **is** an instance of that superclass (see the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)). You should be able to use a subclass instance anywhere a superclass instance is expected.

You'll need to implement a class with the methods you want from `EventTarget` (perhaps delegated to a private `EventTarget` instance) rather than subclassing `EventTarget`.